# Change a serial number on a motherboard...or at least for dmidecode

Tags: linux, hardware

Is there anyway to change the serial number that is output in dmidecode if there is no option in the BIOS to change it.  For some of our servers that have replaced motherboards its hard to keep track of the original serials that are used for warranty information.  Platform is RHEL and this is more targeted towards the HP DL165's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:  You can force an update with SETSYS by loading up HP's utility on a bootable USB stick

[Setsys Utility for HP ProLiant 100 series G5 and G6 Servers (For USB Key-Media)](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3580694&swItem=MTX-1d48ae3f19d945b481c20736d6&prodNameId=3580695&swEnvOID=2081&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=4&idx=1)

Answer (score 4):

You should keep track of the Care Pack number as well as the PN & SN. When HP replaces a motherboard they are *supposed* to update the Care Pack information as well (though I've had issues with that).

They can lookup the new board, see what board it replaced, and lookup the Care Pack that way.

Comment: Sunoracle was able to look up "FRU"s, so HP definitely has something similar.

Comment: yeah I am aware of the being able to look up the PN and SN, I just wanted to get something so that we could be able to script something from the machine itself such as the output of dmidecode since we have well over 2000 HP machines to look after and HP isn't exactly great about updating the SN's on their end.

Comment: The short answer is no, the serial and a few other pieces of information are written to [WORM memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_Once_Read_Many).